# Need clarity on how pricing works on Smooch Sandbox

Tags: wechat, smooch

I have created a free trial account on smooch that gives me access to their WeChat API in the sandbox. However, it is still not clear to me what happens after the 14 day trial period is over. Will I be forced to upgrade to a paid plan even for using the sandbox or is the sandbox always free. Note: My intended use is to develop and test our app against their API and hence I will always need API access in their sandbox. Our production usage will be on a different account with the relevant paid plan. Will really appreciate someone sharing their knowledge around how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The trial period applies only to usage of the Smooch [Public REST API](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/) and [Webhooks](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks), so if you intend to receive and reply to messages programmatically, then the trial will not be sufficient for testing or development beyond the 14 day period. If you intend to receive and respond to messages using one of the built-in Business System integrations like [Slack](https://app.smooch.io/integrations/slack) or [Zendesk](https://app.smooch.io/integrations/zendesk), you can continue to use those integrations after the trial period expires.

If you have a paid account already, you could also create a separate Smooch App for testing under that same account and take advantage of the API access afforded by your plan.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Does WhatsApp and WeChat fall into Business System integration category?

Comment: WhatsApp and WeChat are messaging channels, you can use all messaging channels regardless of trial restrictions